# Why can't I just apply a large amount of selectors to CSS script?

Tags: html, css, styling

I just began learning HTML/CSS a few day ago and I was wondering why a lot of my code that I have been writing recently isn't working properly.

Why can't I simply use many selectors in order to apply all of my desired declarations?

```css
header nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You are targeting `<ul>`. If you want the lines under the text to be removed and the color to be black, target `<a>`. ex. `header nav ul a { text-decoration: none; color: black }`

Comment: It can be helpful to use your browser dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied. In this case if you look at the a element you would see the browser has set underline by default.

Comment: *Why can't I simply use many selectors in order to apply all of my desired declarations?* Huh??

Answer (score 0):

As zer00ne said, you can target the links in the list because you are now targeting the list. just add `a` after the `ul` to do that. here is how.

```css
header nav ul a {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to apply `list-style: none;` to `a` elements.

Comment: I just copied his code. but it worked for the links style.